# Props not being passed through components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Is there any reason the below code wouldn't work, It being populated in the console fine but as soon as I log this data in the child component it says its an empty array

I am trying to pass processedSessions to AllSessions but its being logged as an empty array in AllSessions but a populated on in App.js which is the code you see below

I have tried manually creating variable that is an array and passing this through works fine but effectively I pasting an object from my console into this object so it isn't any different

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AddSession from "./pages/AddSession";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import AllSessions from "./components/AllSessions";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
// import { AddSessionForm } from "./components/AddSessionForm";
// import NavigationButtons from "./components/NavigationButtons";

function App() {
  const [allSessions, setAllSessions] = useState([]);

  const updateAllSessions = (newSession) => {
    console.log("Updating sessions with:", newSession);
    setAllSessions((prevSessions) => [...prevSessions, newSession]);
  };

  // Map over allSessions to process the data
  const processedSessions = allSessions.map((session) => ({
    date: session.date,
    exercise: session.exercise,
    reps: session.reps,
    sets: session.sets,
    weight: session.weight,
  }));

  const sessionArray = [
    {
      date: "1213",
      exercise: "Bench",
      reps: 23423,
      sets: 42353,
      weight: 5435,
    },
  ];

  console.log("Current allSessions:", processedSessions);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        {/* Pass the processedSessions to AllSessions */}
        <Route
          path="/AllSessions"
          element={<AllSessions allSessions={processedSessions} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/AddSession"
          element={<AddSession updateAllSessions={updateAllSessions} />}
        />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you're saying why processedSessions value is empty inside AllSessions component right?

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal yes the Array is being passed through but none of the data within the array is being maintained